# How to retrieve value from database MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

How to get/retrieve value from database MySQL which triggeres by select/option
value my html and php code on picture attached

```
<select name="blok" id="blok">
<option value="B01">B01</option>
<option value="B02">B02</option>
<option value="B03">B03</option>
</select>

<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

$query  = "SELECT brand FROM table WHERE blok = **(value from option)**";'

$result = $mysqli->query($query);'

$row    = $result->fetch_array();'

echo $row[brand];

?>
```

Comment: Google "dropdown select from php form"

Answer (score 0):

you need to place your `select` in a form as follows:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <!-- your form in here -->
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

[(from php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

then access the data in the php script (in this case the file is called action.php) something like this:

```
   $blok = htmlspecialchars($_POST['blok']);  // escaping dodgy chars is a good idea, even if you use prepared statements as below.
```

then insert it into your query.  Be aware though that you should be using prepared statements to insert your data into your query. Examples of which you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: the both code (html and php) within one form without submit button but using select onchange (CMIIW)

Comment: You need to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not storing the "value from option" in any variable.
You should do that, and then insert it in the $query

Comment: if using submit button i know what is variable needed, but if using select/option onchange i have no idea because the both code within one form